# Find controls of another page

Tags: asp.net

I have two aspx pages, PageA and PageB.
I want to find all the controls of PageB in the code behind of PageA without loading PageB.
How can i achieve this?

[EDIT]

I have designer like page which lists all the controls of another selected page.Here i can select an item from a list and add properties or assign css class.

Comment: i loaded pageB in a div and accessed the controls.just wanted to check is there a better way doing this?

Comment: If you could explain what you are hoping to achieve by doing this then someone may be able to advise you on the best method.

Comment: I have designer like page which lists all the controls of another selected page.Here i can select an item from a list and add properties or assign css class.

Comment: please post your code here